# Customizing WooCommerce review-order.php checkout template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, hook-woocommerce

So I am working on WooCommerce with a Child-theme. I have created my structure,

```
/themes/child/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php
```

My goal is just to add some 'static text' to the page. 
So for example, `<h2>Purchase Disclaimer</h2>`

Inside `review-order.php`

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>
<h2>Purchase Disclaimer</h2>
```

My problem is, when I view the page, it then goes,

```
<h2>Purchase Disclaimer</h2>
<h2>Purchase Disclaimer</h2>
```

I don't know why it seems to load it 2 times. Is this a glitch, or am I loading it weird? Perhaps someone could help clarify this issue for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checkout review-order table load first one time and then ajax is making a 2nd loading (for update purposes is suppose), so you have to use a little condition to avoid that:

```
<?php if(!defined( 'DOING_AJAX' )): ?>
<h2>Purchase Disclaimer</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You should avoid **`<h2>`** tag as it's already use for **`<h3 id="order_review_heading">Your order</h3>`**

Alternatively you can use instead a hooked function in **`woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review`** hook this way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'my_custom_funtion');
function my_custom_funtion(){
    ?>
        <h2>Purchase Disclaimer2</h2>
    <?php
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin php files.*

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. Yeah, I was just using that as an example, sorry.  I am going to try the hook. Thanks